# access the outer element of tuple in pandas dataframe groupby object

Tags: python, pandas

I have a groupby object created on a multiindex dataframe (eg (a,b)). I can access the inner groups, with `df.get_group((a,b))`. However, i also want to be able to access the outer group, like `df.get_group((a,))`. I can achieve this indirectly through `df.xs(key,level)` command, but this is not the ideal way to solve the problem. Can somebody help me with this?

```
    df1.get_group(('specialty finance','mortgage finance'))
                                          lasts         prev ticker
industry          sub_industry                                     
specialty finance mortgage finance   190.000000   190.649994   dewh
                  mortgage finance   252.699997   253.350006   grhf
                  mortgage finance  1179.800049  1180.050049   hdfc
                  mortgage finance   693.849976   708.450012   ihfl
                  mortgage finance   450.950012   468.250000  lichf

df1.get_group(('specialty finance',))
ValueError: must supply a a same-length tuple to get_group with multiple grouping keys
```

Comment: What do you mean by inner and outer groups?

Comment: i am referring to the tuple pair as inner and outer groups. In the example df1.get_group(('specialty finance','mortgage finance')), 'specialty finance' is the outer group and ''mortgage finance' is the inner group. a outer group can have many sub-groups, I can access the sub groups as above, but how do I access the outer group (which will list all the sub-groups (inner groups)). I hope i am making sense, the example code clearly shows what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your first `groupby()` that determines the `get_group()` named objects. Had you ran the `groupby` on your original multi-index dataframe by just industry (outer group), you can output to the '*specialty finance*' group alone:

```
df1 = originaldf.groupby(['industry']).get_group('specialty finance')
```

Alternatively, you can continue with current grouping and [iterate](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/groupby-fu-improvements-in-grouping-and-aggregating-data-in-pandas/) through all elements of a `groupby` object, even conditioning grouping according to your specific industry:

```
dfgrp = originaldf.groupby(['industry','sub_industry'])

for industry, sub_industry in dfgrp:
    if 'specialty finance' in industry:
        print(industry)
        print(sub_industry)
```